# anyone know where good tutorials are for starting to brew lager

Tags: yeast, water, lager

I am currently brewing my own beer and its going good. For my next batch I want to make something like a Coors Light or even something that tastes like Fosters or Carlsberg. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question as it stands is a bit to broad.  After some research some more specific lager brewing questions would be more appropriate to this site.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you need to start preparing for temp controlled fermentation as well as good yeast management practices.  That includes starters and learning to pitch more yeast that you would for a normal ale.

A good alternative to lager brewing is to start with styles like Kolsch or American Cream Ale.  These beers usually are light in color and flavor and focus on clean fermenting ale strains.

Lastly, take a look at [Greg Noonan's New Brewing Lager Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0937381829). It give great insight into the mechanics of lager brewing, lager yeast and history.